# How to query if a list contains some value

Tags: java, objectify

I'm trying to convert this JDO query to Objectify query:

```
   Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class,
      "someList.contains(userParam) && someProperty== null");
    query.declareParameters("String userParam");
    query.setRange(0, 1);
    query.execute(user.getId());
```

This is my Objectify implementation however I am not sure if this is correct:

```
    Query<Question> queryResult = dao.query().filter("someProperty", null)
            .filter("someList.contains", user.getId())
            .limit(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectify works like the Java low-level API.  Just use an equality filter on the list property:

```
Query<Question> queryResult = dao.query(User.class)
        .filter("someProperty", null)
        .filter("someList", user.getId())
        .limit(1);
```

Comment: If you wanted to query for `not null`, could you just add the operands?  ie: `filter("someProperty !=", null)`

Comment: Yes, but this is considered a kind of inequality filter with slightly unusual behavior - read the comments about != in the GAE docs for queries and indexes.